# Is it possible to negate a scope in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, named-scope

I have the following scope for my class called `Collection`:

```
scope :with_missing_coins, joins(:coins).where("coins.is_missing = ?", true)
```

I can run `Collection.with_missing_coins.count` and get a result back -- it works great!
Currently, if I want to get collections without missing coins, I add another scope:

```
scope :without_missing_coins, joins(:coins).where("coins.is_missing = ?", false)
```

I find myself writing a lot of these "opposite" scopes. Is it possible to get the opposite of a scope without sacrificing readability or resorting to a lambda/method (that takes `true` or `false` as a parameter)?

Something like this:

```
Collection.!with_missing_coins
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I wouldn't use a single scope for this, but two:

```
scope :with_missing_coins, joins(:coins).where("coins.is_missing = ?", true)
scope :without_missing_coins, joins(:coins).where("coins.is_missing = ?", false)
```

That way, when these scopes are used then it's explicit what's happening. With what numbers1311407 suggests, it is not immediately clear what the `false` argument to `with_missing_coins` is doing.

We should try to write code as clear as possible and if that means being less of a zealot about DRY once in while then so be it.

Answer (score 83):

In Rails 4.2, you can do:

```
scope :original, -> { ... original scope definition ... }
scope :not_original, -> { where.not(id: original) }
```

It'll use a subquery.

Comment: for Mongoid I use `self.not(other_scope.selector)`

Comment: Great idea but in my case, the subquery took twice as long.

Comment: Sure. That is because it has to find the `id`s of all the rows of `original` and then run a query where these ids are excluded. Even though Rails uses nested query, it is doing the work twice

Comment: It's not a subquery, it's an additional query.

Comment: I've only ever seen Rails generate a subquery from this. Do you have a counter-example?

Answer (score 12):

There's no "reversal" of a scope per se, although I don't think resorting to a lambda method is a problem.

```
scope :missing_coins, lambda {|status| 
  joins(:coins).where("coins.is_missing = ?", status) 
}

# you could still implement your other scopes, but using the first
scope :with_missing_coins,    lambda { missing_coins(true) }
scope :without_missing_coins, lambda { missing_coins(false) }
```

then:

```
Collection.with_missing_coins
Collection.without_missing_coins
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this programmatically, without a subquery:

```rb
scope :my_scope, ...

Entity.where.not(Entity.my_scope.where_values_hash)
```

See also: https://makandracards.com/makandra/486959-how-to-negate-scope-conditions-in-rails

*Note this only works with AR queries and does not work with SQL queries.* *E.g. `where('updated_at < ?', 1.hour.ago)` would not be negated.*

Comment: A similar approach with Arel but didn't work for me. https://jbhannah.net/articles/negating-activerecord-scopes

Comment: This only works for very simple where clauses like `where(something: something)`, and if someone adds something like `where('updated_at < ?', 1.hour.ago)` to the scope, it will break `where_values_hash` in a very hard to track down way.

Answer (score 3):

With Rails 7, you can use [`invert_where`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-invert_where):

```rb
scope :with_missing_coins, -> { joins(:coins).where(coins: { is_missing: true }) }
scope :without_missing_coins, -> { with_missing_coins.invert_where }
```

However;

1. It will invert everything before it, so `Collection.with_something.without_missing_coins` will invert `with_something` too, returning rows "without something". You'll need to watch out for the order of scopes and conditions: `Collection.without_missing_coins.with_something`.
2. Since it inverts the condition and not the argument (ie. it converts it to `!= true`, rather than `= false`), the negated scope will include null values too; unless the field is defined as `null: false`.

So it's probably better and clearer to write them explicitly. If you want to merge them, maybe you can use another parameterized scope:

```rb
scope :missing_coins, ->(is_missing) { joins(:coins).where(coins: { is_missing: is_missing }) }
scope :with_missing_coins, -> { missing_coins(true) }
scope :without_missing_coins, -> { missing_coins(false) }
```

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**

```rb
Collection.with_missing_coins.invert_where
```

**More details**

Rails 7 introduced [`invert_where`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-invert_where)

It allows you to invert an entire where clause instead of manually applying conditions

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  scope :active, -> { where(accepted: true, locked: false) }
end

User.where(accepted: true)
# SELECT * FROM users WHERE accepted = TRUE

User.where(accepted: true).invert_where
# SELECT * FROM users WHERE accepted != TRUE

User.active
# SELECT * FROM users WHERE accepted = TRUE AND locked = FALSE

User.active.invert_where
# SELECT * FROM users WHERE NOT (accepted = TRUE AND locked = FALSE)
```

Be careful, compare these variants

```
User.where(role: "admin").active.invert_where
# SELECT * FROM users WHERE NOT (role = 'admin' AND accepted = TRUE AND locked = FALSE)

User.active.invert_where.where(role: "admin")
# SELECT * FROM users WHERE NOT (accepted = TRUE AND locked = FALSE) AND role = 'admin'
```

And look at this

```
User.where(accepted: true).invert_where.where(locked: false).invert_where
# SELECT * FROM users WHERE NOT (accepted != TRUE AND locked = FALSE)
```

`invert_where` inverts all where conditions before it. Therefore it's better to avoid using this method in scopes because it could lead to unexpected results

Much better to use this method explicitly and only in the beginning of where chain immediately after it is necessary to invert all the previous conditions

Answer (score 2):

this might just work, did not test it much. uses rails 5 I guess rails 3 has where_values method instead of where_clause.

```
scope :not, ->(scope_name) do 
              query = self
              send(scope_name).joins_values.each do |join|
                   query = query.joins(join)
              end
              query.where((send(scope_name).
                    where_clause.send(:predicates).reduce(:and).not))
end
```

usage

`Model.not(:scope_name)`

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @bill-lipa is good, but beware when the scopes you want involve associations or attachments.

If we have the following scope to select all users with a resume attached:

```
scope :with_resume, -> { joins(:resume_attachment) }
```

The following negation will cause an exception if `with_resume` is empty:

```
scope :without_resume, -> { where.not(id: with_resume) } 
#=> users.without_resume
#=> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
```

Therefore you'll need to check first to get the results you want:

```
scope :without_resume, -> { with_resume.any? ? where.not(id: with_resume) : where.not(id: []) }
```

Answer (score -2):

**Update** . Now Rails 6 adds convenient and nifty negative enum methods.

```
# All inactive devices
# Before
Device.where.not(status: :active)
#After 
Device.not_active
```

Blog post
[here](https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/02/26/rails-6-negative-scopes-for-enum-values.html)

Comment: this does not answer the question. question uses a `join` and does not use any `enum`s