# Rails 5, scope opposite to another scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way in Rails 5 that I can use the opposite (negation) of a scope? 
For example, given I have the following scope

`scope :missing_coordinates, -> { where(latitude: [nil, '']).or(where(longitude: [nil, ''])) }`

is there any way I can use the opposite of that scope like:

`Places.not(missing_coordinates)`

which would return the ones that have both the latitude and longitude?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to negate a scope in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054188/is-it-possible-to-negate-a-scope-in-rails-3)

Comment: I added Rails 5 to my question. Also the answer given is really not negating the scope but solving his problem in a different way (creating two different scopes), which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes unfortunately even Rails5 doesn't have a built in modifier for getting the opposite of a scope.

Answer (score 3):

How about creating a method that takes the entire collection, and subtracts the `missing_coordinates`.

```
self.not_missing_coordinates
    Places.all - Places.missing_coordinates
end
```

This lets you call `Places.not_missing_coordinates`. I looked around the docs and couldn't find anything quite like negation of a scope in the way you've described.

Comment: You are creating the opposite scope but I don't want to repeat the `latitude: [nil, '']` part.

Comment: So basically you want the results of an opposite scope, without creating another one? (I could be misunderstanding here) I think it is better to simply create two different scopes for concision.

Comment: I don't know about Rails 5, but couldn't you just negate the other scope?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Something like `not(name_of_other_scope)`. But it's not working for me.

Comment: This link by pivotal labs ends with a solution similar to what you're looking for: https://content.pivotal.io/blog/logically-negating-an-activerecord-scope. If done correctly the end solution should look like `Places.not(:missing_coordinates)`.

Comment: you could also turn this solution into a scope by doing `scope :not_missing_coordinates, -> { all - missing_coordinates }` if using a scope not a method is important

Answer (score 3):

There is no built in solution, but you can pass params to scope:

```
scope :missing_coordinates, ->(missing = true){ missing ?
       where(latitude: [nil, '']).or(where(longitude: [nil, ''])) :
       where.not(latitude: '').where.not(longitude: '') 
}
```

Call:

```
Places.missing_coordinates
Places.missing_coordinates(false) #opposite
```

Or you can define two scopes as following:

```
scope :missing_coordinates, -> { where(latitude: [nil, '']).or(where(longitude: [nil, '']))}
scope :not_missing_coordinates, -> { where.not(id: missing_coordinates) }
```

Comment: Is your `:not_missing_coordinates` scope correct?  You might need to add `.ids` like this:
`scope :not_missing_coordinates, -> { where.not(id: missing_coordinates.ids) }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```
scope :not, ->(scope_name) { query = self
          send(scope_name).joins_values.each do |join|
          query = query.joins(join)
        end
                                        query.where((send(scope_name).where_clause.send(:predicates).reduce(:and).not))}
```

usage

```
Model.not(:scope_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 7, yes they've introduced "invert_where", which will invert your scope.

https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#

So in the author's case:

```
Places.missing_coordinates.invert_where
```

Answer (score 0):

@harsimar-sandu's answer gave me this idea:

`scope :not, ->(scope_name) { where.not(id: send(scope_name).select(:id))}`